# Shopping Cart : Updating and Deleting product from the cart

Tags: php, html, shopping-cart

hey im trying to make an online shopping website but im stuck at the cart section

im trying to show the quantity of product in the Text Box and update it also which doesn't seem to work with my code and also im unable to remove product from the cart.

im using check box for delete and an update button of type submit and an text box to show the quntity

here's code the my cart.php page..

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <table align="center" width="700px" bgcolor="skyblue">

    <tr align="center">
        <th>Remove</th>
        <th>Products</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th>Total Price</th>
    </tr>

<?php 

$total = 0;

global $con;

$ip = getIp();

$select_price = "select * from cart where ip_addr = '$ip'";

$run_price = mysqli_query($con, $select_price);

while ($p_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_price)) {

    $pro_id = $p_price['p_id'];
    $pro_qty = $p_price['qty'];

    $pro_price = "select * from products where product_id = '$pro_id'";

    $run_pro_price = mysqli_query($con, $pro_price);

    $select_qty = "select * from cart where p_id = '$pro_id'";

    $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $select_qty);

    $row_qty = mysqli_fetch_array($run_qty);

    $qty = $row_qty['qty'];

    while ($pp_price = mysqli_fetch_array($run_pro_price)) {

        $product_price = array($pp_price['product_price']);
        $product_title = $pp_price['product_title'];
        $product_image = $pp_price['product_image'];

        $single_price = $pp_price['product_price'];

        $values = array_sum($product_price);

        $total += $values;

?>

    <tr align="center">
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="remove[]" value="<?php echo 
$pro_id; ?>"></td>
        <td><?php echo $product_title; ?><br>
        <img src="Admin_area/product_image/<?php echo $product_image; ?>" 
width="60px" height="60px">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="qty" size="4px" value="<?php echo $qty; 
?>"></td>  // Calling the $qty variable which store the product quantity

        <?php

        if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {

            $qty = $_POST['qty'];
            $update_qty = "update cart set qty='$qty' where p_id = 
'$pro_id'";
            $run_qty = mysqli_query($con, $update_qty);

            $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;

            $total = $total*$qty;

            echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";

        }

        ?>

        <td>&#8360 <?php echo $single_price; ?></td> 
    </tr>

    <?php } } ?>

    <tr align="right">
        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px;"><b>Sub Total:</b></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="padding: 10px;">&#8360 <?php echo $total; ?>
</td>
    </tr>

    <tr align="center">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="update_cart" 
value="Update Cart"></td>
        <td><button><a href="index.php" style="text-decoration: none; color: 
black;">Continue</a></button></td>
        <td><button><a href="checkout.php" style="text-decoration: none; 
color: black;">Checkout</a></button></td>
    </tr>


    </table>

    </form>

    <?php 

    function updatecart(){

    $ip = getIp();

    if (isset($_POST['update_cart'])) {

 // when update cart button clicked delete all product which are checked

        foreach ($_POST['remove'] as $remove_id) {

            $delete_product = "delete from cart where p_id = '$remove_id' 
AND ip_addr = '$ip'";

            $run_delete = mysqli_query($con,$delete_product);

            if ($run_delete) {

        echo "<script>alert('Inside Function');</script>";


                echo "<script>window.open('cart.php','_self')</script>";
            }

        }

    }

    elseif (isset($_POST['continue'])) {

        echo "<script>window.open('index.php','_self')</script>";

    }

}

echo @$update_cart = updatecart();

?>          

    </div>
```

Comment: Side Note: If you're building new code with mysqli, please look into using Prepared Statements for any query that has variables inserted into it (especially if that variable comes from user-end data).